# jquery, appending using a variable with spaces

Tags: jquery, variables, append

I am storing and using a variable to append a value (using jquery). The issue is, if the variable has any spaces in the name stored in it, it will only append the first word. So for example, if I store the value "New Title" in the variable, it will only set the value to "New". The interesting thing is title is definitely stored, it's just outsde the quotations of the value like this

my code looks like so

```
//store name from input
var appName = $(".appNameInput").val();

//much lower in the code append using the stored value
$(".adminLeftTable").append("<input type='radio' name='checkAppNm' value= " + appName + ">");
```

Comment: have you looked in your debugger to see if the value is getting set correctly?

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example showing the problem?

Comment: The value is storing perfectly fine, the issue is the value= " + appName , is closing the quotes around the first item - so if i store "new title", it appends like value="new" title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing delimiters around the value:

```
$(".adminLeftTable").append("<input type='radio' name='checkAppNm' value='" + appName + "'>");
```

Answer (score 2):

add a `'` quote wrapper like this:

```
$(".adminLeftTable").append("<input type='radio' name='checkAppNm' value='" + appName + "'>");
//-------------------------here------------------------------------------^---------------^
```

---

So if your value is `New Title` then only first word would be assigned as the value, to overcome this you have to put `'` single quotes as per your code requirements.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you're not wrapping the `appName` value in quotes. Your code is generating

```
<input type='radio' name='checkAppNm' value=New Title>
```

when it needs to generate

```
    <input type='radio' name='checkAppNm' value='New Title'>
```